# is there any way to force stop the ProcessMessageAsync handler when the thread keeps running in background?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

My function app tried to make a call to Service Bus to collect messages every 5 minutes and cancel after 5 seconds to response the consumer.

```
// the client that owns the connection and can be used to create senders and receivers                
client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

// the processor that reads and processes messages from the queue
processor = client.CreateProcessor(topicName, subscriptionName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());

// handler to process SB message async
processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;

// handle in receiving SB messages 
async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
{
            string body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
            var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(body);
            Messages.Add(message);

            // complete the message. Message is deleted from the queue
            await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
}

// handle any errors when receiving messages
Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
{
            Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());
            var errorObject = new JObject();
            errorObject["ErrorMessage"] = $"Error processing the request from the queue: {args.Exception.Message}";
            Messages.Add(errorObject);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
}

// handler to process any errors
processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

// cancel the token after 5 secs
tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

// start process async
await processor.StartProcessingAsync(tokenSource.Token);

// end the while loop for any cancelation process (5 secs)
while (!tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested) {}

// stop or end process async
await processor.StopProcessingAsync(tokenSource.Token);
```

Issue happened when the client/consumer/postman cancel the function app calls say multiple times and it cancel gracefully the call from client/postman.

However, in function app the thread pool still running and when there's a message in the queue it will automatically pick up the message. So, when you call the function app to get the message it say no message to pick up.

Is any one experience this scenario?

To simulate:

- Call function app and cancel while processing (3x)
- Send message to service bus and it will automatically be pickup by the message handler.

Workaround is to stop and start the function app to resolve it.

Comment: Why don't you use queue trigger?

Comment: This is different use case where external/vendor need to call this API every 5 mins to check/query for any message in service bus queue..  However, at their end, they cancel manually the API call which cause the message handler to properly cleanup up..

Answer (score 0):

> - Call function app and cancel while processing (3x)
> - Send message to service bus and it will automatically be pickup by the message handler.

In order to achieve the above scenario, I have used the code below in my service bus queue trigger:-

I am using the below **method to cancel the Function servicebus processing:-**

```cs
await processor.CloseAsync();
await client.DisposeAsync();
```

**My Function.cs:-**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Primitives;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

namespace FunctionApp34
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private static IQueueClient queueClient;
        private static ServiceBusProcessor processor;
        private static ServiceBusClient client;
        private static CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("sid", Connection = "Connection")] string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");

            // create a new token source
            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            // create a new ServiceBusClient object
            client = new ServiceBusClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Connection"));

            // create a new ServiceBusProcessor object
            processor = client.CreateProcessor("sid", new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());

            // register the message handler
            processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;

            // register the error handler
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

            // cancel the token after 5 secs
            tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            // start process async
            await processor.StartProcessingAsync(tokenSource.Token);

            // end the while loop for any cancelation process (5 secs)
            while (!tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested) { }

            // stop or end process async
            await processor.StopProcessingAsync(tokenSource.Token);

            // close the ServiceBusClient and ServiceBusProcessor objects
            await processor.CloseAsync();
            await client.DisposeAsync();
        }

        private static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            // process the message
            Console.WriteLine($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{args.Message.SequenceNumber} Body:{args.Message.Body}");

            // complete the message
            await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
        }

        private static Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            // log the error
            Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());

            // abandon the message
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the POC using SB trigger. I replicate the issue in using httptrigger with get method. i.e.


public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)